# createuser: error: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: sql, postgresql, saleor

I am trying to set up postgres through this documentation: https://docs.saleor.io/docs/getting-started/installation-macos/

I installed pgadmin4 and also through homebrew.

However, I am not able to execute this command

```html
$ createuser --superuser --pwprompt saleor
```

it returns to say that

```html
createuser: error: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "zijie"
```

Interestingly, I am able to log in psql

```html
Password for user postgres: 
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.
```

Can someone advise me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Try createuser with `-U postgres`  option?

Comment: hey I tried su - postgres 
but it returned
"Password:
su: Sorry"

Comment: Hmm so somehow you are able to log in as postgres. Without figuring out what’s up, the quick workaround is just to do `CREATE USER saleor SUPERUSER PASSOWRD ‘your_password';` from the `psql` prompt

Comment: hello i tried that, how do i follow up from there. thanks!